# High Disk Usage /dev/vda3

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, vps

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Currently have a website hosted on the above version, it is a VPS.

Under hard disk usage something called /dev/vda3 is using the most space.

85 971.38 MB used out of 99 724.34 MB total.

How can I identify what it is please?

I'm somewhat new to linux so I'm trying to diagnose this myself before calling in help.

Comment: `df` will show where each filesystem (/dev/vda3, 1st column) is mounted (last column). Then you can `cd` to that directory and do `sudo du -sk * .[^.]*` to see how much each directory is using. You can then drill down in to each directory and repeat `sudo du -sk * .[^.]*` to narrow it down.

Comment: @WayneVosberg Thanks, I can see it is mainly the website I have hosted, mainly backup files / cache files, what is the best command to permanently delete these?

Comment: `rm -rf directory_name` will permanently delete that folder and everything below it. Be very careful you know what you are deleting!!

Comment: I do, thank you, I found the following command online but it doesn't seem to be working.. the folder contains 100s and 100s of .png files: rm -f /path/to/directory/{*,.*}

Comment: You need -rf for directories.

Comment: @WayneVosberg I've tried deleting them with the RM command but I get 'argument list is too long' error. I've seen a few solutions on google on how to fix this by using the 'find' command, all the files are .png. If I SSH into the folder "pub/media/captcha/base" and use this command "find . -name "*.png" -delete" will it just delete the pngs in the base folder or everything outside of it as well?

Comment: Ah - you are deleting the png files themselves and not the parent directory. If you use find with -delete it will remove all png files in all subdirectories below where you are. If you want to remove just the png files in the directory you are in you could use xargs: `ls *.png | xargs rm -f` -- xargs will process the list of files in chunks so you don't hit 'argument list too long' error.

Comment: @WayneVosberg thanks for taking the time to help, much appreciated! edit: That xargs command you gave has also said argument list too long as well?

Comment: Did `ls *.png | xargs rm -f` work? I was just thinking the `ls *.png` would hit the same 'line too long' error. If so, you could do `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.png"  -delete` to restrict the find to the current folder (not children).

Comment: I got this error: find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -name, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it). Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: Too fast for me -- I corrected the command in the previous post.

Comment: haha, cheers, it seems to be working now :), again, appreciated!